# Align a Button and a Dropdown Button in the Center Pane

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, arcgis-js-api

This is probably a simple question but I just started with Dojo/Javascript and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

I started creating my Dojo application in a programmatically way and all I want to know is **how to properly align widgets** (in my case they are a Toggle Button and a Dropdown Button) in the center pane one next to each other and **with the right spacing between them** (the center pane contains a map and I want those buttons peacefully lying on it without covering/limiting its space with another panel). I'd like to have the "Maps" Dropdown Button right next to the "Legend/Layers" Toggle Button aligned to it and rightly spaced.

When I specify the region (in my case the one where the map is with id="mapDiv") creating them, they miserly overlap one on top of the other but that's the region I want them to be..just one next to each other.

I know this might sound a GIS/Mapping question but I think it's more stright Dojo/Javascript (CSS/HTML?) related and that's why I'm asking it here.

I set up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5od8fcm/1/) `code` to show you what I mean

Thanks in advance for your help,

m

Comment: it has a lot of issues, but basically, get rid of ALL your `position:absolute` declarations and work from there. Just remember: most of the times `position:absolute` is wrong, and even in the limited times it looks correct, it's wrong again.

Comment: Hi @Devin, thanks for replying. You have to excuse my lack of experience but I'm not really following you. Isn't the only "absolute" declaration the one for the .esriSimpleSliderTL (I don't like the default position of the zoom in/out buttons). I update the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o5od8fcm/2/) following your suggestion but I'm still stuck on the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, check your code with inspector and you'll see all your elements have inline styles, many of them with "absolute" position. Your problem is here:

```
 <span class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitBorderContainer-child diji…ijitBorderContainerPane dijitAlignMapDiv dijitDropDownButton" widgetid="downButtonMaps" style="left: 5px; top: 56px; position: absolute;">

    <span class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode" role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick"></span>
    <input class="dijitOffScreen" type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" aria-hidden="true" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" value=""></input>

</span>
```

So just add this line in your CSS stylesheet

```
.dijitReset {
    position: relative !important;
}
```

and it should work

Comment: WOW, did I write that? :-| I wrote the code without knowing that! Well, next time I'll check it more carefully. Thanks for your help, yes, it did work! ;-)